# Run airflow commands on official Airflow docker-compose

Tags: docker, airflow

I am using the oficial `docker-compose.yml` to run `airflow 2.1.4` locally and i'm having trouble understanding what happens when i run some `airflow` commands on the `airflow-init` service(file below).

This is the log output:
[log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KekJV.jpg)

I am not understanding why i have repeated instructions. Should i be running this `command` from `airflow-init` in a separate entrypoint script?

Thanks

```sh
airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    # yamllint disable rule:line-length
    command:
      - -c
      - |
        function ver() {
          printf "%04d%04d%04d%04d" $${1//./ }
        }
        airflow_version=$$(gosu airflow airflow version)
        airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${airflow_version})
        min_airflow_version=2.1.0
        min_airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${min_airflow_version})
        if (( airflow_version_comparable < min_airflow_version_comparable )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;31mERROR!!!: Too old Airflow version $${airflow_version}!\e[0m"
          echo "The minimum Airflow version supported: $${min_airflow_version}. Only use this or higher!"
          echo
          exit 1
        fi
        if [[ -z "${AIRFLOW_UID}" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: AIRFLOW_UID not set!\e[0m"
          echo "If you are on Linux, you SHOULD follow the instructions below to set "
          echo "AIRFLOW_UID and AIRFLOW_GID environment variables, otherwise files will be owned by root."
          echo "For other operating systems you can get rid of the warning with manually created .env file:"
          echo "    See: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#setting-the-right-airflow-user"
          echo
        fi
        one_meg=1048576
        mem_available=$$(($$(getconf _PHYS_PAGES) * $$(getconf PAGE_SIZE) / one_meg))
        cpus_available=$$(grep -cE 'cpu[0-9]+' /proc/stat)
        disk_available=$$(df / | tail -1 | awk '{print $$4}')
        warning_resources="false"
        if (( mem_available < 4000 )) ; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough memory available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 4GB of memory required. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((mem_available * one_meg)))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( cpus_available < 2 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough CPUS available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 2 CPUs recommended. You have $${cpus_available}"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( disk_available < one_meg * 10 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough Disk space available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 10 GBs recommended. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((disk_available * 1024 )))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if [[ $${warning_resources} == "true" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: You have not enough resources to run Airflow (see above)!\e[0m"
          echo "Please follow the instructions to increase amount of resources available:"
          echo "   https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#before-you-begin"
          echo
        fi
        mkdir -p /sources/logs /sources/dags /sources/plugins
        chown -R "${AIRFLOW_UID}:${AIRFLOW_GID}" /sources/{logs,dags,plugins}
        /entrypoint airflow connections import /sources/connections.json  
        /entrypoint airflow variables import /sources/variables.json
      
    # yamllint enable rule:line-length
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}
    user: "0:${AIRFLOW_GID:-0}"
    volumes:
      - .:/sources
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS which is just a convenience stuff for very quickly installing dependencies if you want to try things out.

You should **NOT** use it for anything else precisely because you are going to observe what you see here - that installing new dependencies dynamically happens EVERY TIME you run ANY command.

As explained here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/entrypoint.html#installing-additional-requirements you should build and use your own custom image when you want to add dependencies. Read more here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html where you find instructions and plenty of useful examples.

Comment: Makes total sense! Thanks

Comment: I don't think that covers it all.
I have moved the part of installing python packages to a custom image, and still i get repeated instructions, on my logs.
I believe this is due to having the /entrypoint repeated, however i didn't find another way of running the airflow commands that i need

Comment: You probably still have _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS set in your docker-compose.